# How to code a substr version that holds leading zeros in numeric values (in R)?

Tags: r, string, double, substr

While preparing a function that converts normalized double precision numbers to decimal numbers, I needed something like following:

```
substr(01001011, 2, 5) # what is in fact:"0010" (because leading 0 is ignored)
substr(01001011, 2, 5) # what I want:"1001"
substr("01001011", 2, 5) # "1001"; gives what I want BUT the following:
```

In `substr("01001011", 2, 5)`, it is impossible (for me) to turn it to a function since `input=01001011` and double quote concatenations very very problematic. Each time the user must manually enter the value of argument not in in function's call but also in the body of the function where `substr(...)` part is located.

The problem caused by the fact that `01001011` is hold as numeric and hence all leading 0s are ignored.

```
01001011 # [1] 1001011
class(01001011) # "numeric"

substrCorrectly <- function(x) {
substr("x", 2, 5) }
```

For example, for number "01001011";

```
substrCorrectly <- function(x) {
substr("01001011", 2, 5) }
substrCorrectly(01001011) # "1001"
```

This function is definitely very ugly, and against the notion of function: Each time user must change the body of function before applying it!

Any idea?

More examples:

```
substr(000101001011, 1, 4) # "1010"; but what I want is 0001 here. 
substr(10001, 1, 2) # "10" and what I want (10) coincides since 1 is leading.
```

Comment: Is there a way you can figure out how many digits the number should have? In the first examples you provide it's always 8....

Comment: @kath Yes there is a way: in normalized double precision storage of numbers in memory, the 0th bit is sign, 1st-11th (11 bits) are exponents, 12th-63th (52 bits) are significand. Hence, you may well assume that the number of digits of the number in hand is _always_ 11 digits!

Comment: Hope this can help : `formatC(000101001011, flag = "0", width = 12, format = "d")`

Comment: Or with `sprintf`, `substr(sprintf("%012d", 000101001011), 1, 4)`

Comment: @Clemsang and Ronak Shah, I am infinitely thankful to both of you. I am not in a position which solution is better and more time saving. Either of you can write as a solution.

Comment: `substrCorrectly <- function(x) {
x <- formatC(x, flag="0", width=8, format="d");
substr(x, 2, 5) };
substrCorrectly(01001011)  # "1001"`

Comment: Clemsang can go ahead and write a solution as he commented first. Basically it's the same thing done in a different way. We can also use `str_pad` from `stringr`. Initially, I was not aware that length of string is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `formatC` that will allows to keep first `0s`

```
substrCorrectly <- function(x) { 
  x <- formatC(x, flag="0", width=8, format="d") 
  substr(x, 2, 5) 
}
substrCorrectly(01001011) # "1001"
```